# Why did Korath leave the Starforce and how did he end up with Ronan?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

We know Korath from *Guardians of the Galaxy*, he is the leader of the group of Kree in the opening that fight Star Lord for the orb. In the film he also appears to be a "high up" Kree member for Ronan's forces.

However, watching *Captain Marvel* last night he shows up in Yon-Rogg's squad in the Starforce.

**Why did Korath leave the Starforce and how did he end up with Ronan?**

---

I am mainly looking for answers from the MCU canon including interviews from the writers and directors but lacking any information there answers from the comics are fine too.

Comment: It's a small galaxy after all.

Comment: This is speculative, so I can't post an answer, but the iteration of Ronan shown in CM is, according to exec producer Jonathan Schwartz, "an earlier version of Ronan, who has not become the radical zealot that we saw in Guardians of the Galaxy".  It's possible that Korath shares these views, and follows Ronan because he's becoming more extreme in his outlook.

Comment: Korath probably left the Starforce in *SHAME!*, after his *FAILURE* to capture *VERS* *ON* earth.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, Korath was originally introduced in *GotG (2014)*, where he was seen working as muscle for Ronan, who served as the film's primary antagonist. Thanks to Drax, he dies in this film too. *GotG* is, therefore, no help in bridging this gap.

Also as noted, he later shows up in *Captain Marvel* set about 20 years earlier. This film is also no help — and apparently, a lot has changed between the two time periods.

> Korath was originally introduced in 2014’s Guardians of the Galaxy, where he was seen working as muscle for Ronan, who served as the film’s primary antagonist. While Korath met his demise at the hands of Drax the Destroyer in this film, he later reappeared in 2019’s Captain Marvel, which was set around 20 years prior to Guardians. His appearance in Captain Marvel revealed Korath’s role in the Kree military unit, Starforce, before he served Ronan. However, over the course of these two appearances, Korath’s character received little exploration and he spent most his time relegated to the role of stony-faced muscle for larger villains. That all changes in What If…?.
>
> Korath’s introduction in “What If… T’Challa Became a Star-Lord” mirrors his original introduction in Guardians of the Galaxy. Like Peter Quill in the opening to Guardians, T’Challa is seen breaking into the Temple of the Power Stone on the planet Morag. When he takes the orb containing the Power Stone, Korath arrives, holding him at gunpoint and demanding to know his identity. However, whereas Quill’s introduction as “Star-Lord” was met with bewilderment from Korath, when T’Challa unmasks, the Kree enforcer immediately begins singing his praises. Not only has Korath heard of this version of Star-Lord, he’s a fan. The result is an outpouring of emotion and sincerity never before seen in any of Korath’s live-action appearances.
>
> <sub>[News Concerns, What If Gives Korath More Personality Than He Ever Had In Movies](https://newsconcerns.com/what-if-gives-korath-more-personality-than-he-ever-had-in-movies/)</sub>

Unfortunately, *What If…?* is no help either, as it picks up at the same point as *GotG*.

To confirm, his official story briefing between his appearances has not been fully detailed. It may yet be in a future work.

Any hints in Ronan’s appearances, since he’s associated with Korath in the same films?

The version seen in *Captain Marvel* is the leader of the Accusers and has yet to embrace the bloody markings he wears in GotG that earned him the title of a zealot. However, while his appearance in the film is also interesting, it also does nothing to detail his future fate as a zealot in partnership with Thanos & leading Korath as his henchman.

At the time this question was posted, we’re no closer to knowing what happens in between.

Comment: There's apparently something in the *Marvel Studios Visual Dictionary*.